# Getting one specific entry from database error

Tags: android, database

I am trying to get one specific entry out of my DB with following code:

```
Object specificObject = myDbHelper.getObject(int id, int level);

// code in DataBaseHelper:

public Object getObject(int id, int level){

        c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE ID =" + id + " AND LEVEL = " + level, null);

        Object q = new Object();
        q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
        q.setName(c.getString(2));
        q.setFile(c.getInt(3));
        q.setAnswer(c.getString(4));
        return q;


    }
```

The problem is this results in following error:

09-24 11:12:52.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7388): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Any ideas? It seems that it knows that it has a size of one (one entry?) but i don't get the index -1 requested issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before accessing data from cursor you have to move first record.

```
c.moveToFirst()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like:

```
c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE ID =" + id + " AND LEVEL = " + level, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
      Object q = new Object();
      q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
      q.setName(c.getString(2));
      q.setFile(c.getInt(3));
      q.setAnswer(c.getString(4));
      return q;
    }
return null;
```